# JQuery 3.1.1 vs 2.2.4 change in behavior appending rows to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code:

```
$('<TABLE />').append('<TR><TD>1</TD></TR>').appendTo('BODY');
```

results in slightly different DOM structures.

Under 2.2.4 you get <TABLE><TBODY><TR>...

```js
var table = $('<TABLE />');
table.append('<TR><TD>1</TD></TR>').appendTo('BODY');
console.log(table.prop('outerHTML'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Under 3.1.1 you get <TABLE><TR>...

```js
var table = $('<TABLE />');
table.append('<TR><TD>1</TD></TR>').appendTo('BODY');
console.log(table.prop('outerHTML'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(one has a `TBODY` and one does not)

This causes problems if you later have selectors like `#id TBODY TR` (to get all the body rows, and no header rows).

I've reviewed the [jQuery Core 3.0 Upgrade Guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/) and can't see anything that might be related.

So my question is... is this expected behaviour or a bug in JQuery?

Comment: By design: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3976

Comment: I hope it gets added to Upgrade Guide, was spending considerable amount of time finding cause of broken tables after 2.x -> 3.x upgrade https://github.com/jquery/jquery.com/issues/232